# Having issues trying to display_items in a text based game

Tags: python, function

Im currently learning python and making a text based game.

Im trying to use a function to create a command to show the items available like:

`def display_items(): print("You currently have " + str(inventory)) display_items()`

However, I keep receiving a syntax error on the "def display items():"

`yes_no  = ["yes", "no"] directions = ["left", "right", "forward", "backwards"] inventory = { 'Water bottle' : 1, 'Bandage' : 2`
}
player_health = 5`

I've tried re-wording it to show_inventory, display_items ect etc
ive also tried putting in individual items to display.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your indentation is correct. Also pass 'inventory' to to the function as an argument

```
def display_items(inventory): 
    print("You currently have " + str(inventory)) 

display_items(inventory)
```